# Change form/formset error messages

Tags: django, django-forms

How can I change the 'error' messages that I get when using a formset.

For example:

'Please submit 1 or more forms.'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Please submit %d or fewer forms.` ValidationError exception can be raised by `BaseFormSet.full_clean` method, I guess you can override this one to achieve what you want.

```
def full_clean(self):
    super().full_clean()  # Populates self._non_form_errors
    for e in self._non_form_errors.as_data():
        if e.code == 'too_few_forms':
            e.message = "custom message"
```